# How to arrange values of a 2D array in a JTextField

Tags: java, swing

I did not find any answer to my issue in the archive. 
 
I am having issues setting a 5x5 sequence of numbers on my jtextfield.
This is my code

```
private void btnperformAction(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                           
        int [][] boardOne = defineBoard(); //initializes matrix   
        fillBoard(boardOne); //adds integers values to the matrix
        int i,j;

        for(i = 0; i < boardOne.length; i++){
            for(j = 0; j < boardOne[i].length; j++){
                txtField.setText(txtField.getText() + boardOne[i][j]); 
         }
        }
```

And this is the way I need the output to show.

```
    5   16  36  52  70  
    8   26  35  60  73  
    12  23  -1  51  74  
    3   27  34  59  68  
    14  30  47  64  80
```

And what I get on my jtextfield is this

```
5
16
36
52
70
8
26
35
60
73
12
23
-1
51
74
3
27
34
59
68
14
30
47
64
80
```

How can I format in a 5x5 fashion? 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like what you want to use is a [`JTable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) instead. However for better help sooner post a proper [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in mentioned in your earlier question for the 4x4 matrix, you can use a `StringBuilder` as follows

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < boardOne.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < boardOne[i].length; j++){
        builder.append(boardOne[i][j]);
        builder.append(" ");
    }
    builder.append("\n");
}

txtField.setText(builder.toString());
```

Note that this is just a simple space separated String. It will not even out the spacing so that it looks like a perfect grid, as in your question. You will need to calculate the exact space padding needed based on the number of digits, for such a thing. So if that is important to you, go for a JTable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use JTextArea and add newline at the end of each row. If you are using JTextField it cannot support multiline, it is on one line only.
Paste the code in any java file and execute the main method.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frm = new JFrame();
        JTextArea txtArea = new JTextArea();
        txtArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        JButton btn = new JButton("DO ARRANGE");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int[][] boardOne = new int[][]{
                        {5,   16,  36,  52,  70},
                        {8,   26,  35,  60,  73},
                        {12,  23,  -1,  51,  74},
                        {3,   27,  34,  59,  68},
                        {14,  30,  47,  64,  80}
                };
                int i, j;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (i = 0; i < boardOne.length; i++) {
                    for (j = 0; j < boardOne[i].length; j++) {
                        sb.append(boardOne[i][j]);
                        if (j < boardOne[i].length - 1) {
                            sb.append(" ");
                        }
                    }
                    sb.append("\r\n");
                }
                txtArea.setText(sb.toString());

            }
        });
        frm.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frm.getContentPane().add(btn, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frm.getContentPane().add(txtArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frm.pack();
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```